# Custom installation profile with standard content

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

For a school project I'm trying to use a custom installation profile to pre-install a couple of modules such as Drupal Commerce.

The problem I'm running into is the fact that although my installation extends the *standard* installation it doesn't seem to install things like the standard content types, frontpage, etc.

I can't seem to find anything about this by googling or reading the official documentation, so I think I'm just missing something super obvious.

Note: I used Drupal Console to generate a profile to which I added all the needed modules and themes. And in the .install file I use code to set Bartik and Seven as the themes for the page and admin respectively. So what I'm missing might be the things in the config files?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Profiles don't support extension/inheritance yet so it's a little unclear what you mean by _my installation extends the standard installation_. Could you edit the question and give a bit more detail about the steps you've taken so far? Maybe you've copied the standard profile and renamed some things? The answer is essentially that most things are in config files (in the standard/config/install and optional folders), and the rest in the `standard_install()` function, but it's difficult to advise exactly what you need to do without knowing what you've done

Comment: @Clive I used Drupal Console to generate a profile to which I added all the needed modules and themes. And in the .install file I use code to set Bartik and Seven as the themes for the page and admin respectively.
So what I'm missing might be the things in the config files?

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't tried doing it that way yet so I'm not sure what it spits out. Yes it does sound like the config files may be missing